# Javascript How to achieve conditional/ nested filters in drop down

Tags: javascript, php

I have a category dropdown1 (with id: `#blogcat`), which filters the blog posts of wordpress which is a default functionality.

I have another custom type drop down (with id: `#blogarticletype`).

**Requirement is:**

Consider blogs:

`Blog 4` which belongs to category `Category 1` and type `abc`

`Blog 5`  which belongs to category `Category 1` and type `xyz`

***This is Working for category dd alone***

If i select Category 1 from 1st drop down(ie category dropdown), it filters me out Blog4 and Blog5 -  http://example.com/index.php/blog/category1

***This is working for article type dd alone:***
http://example.com/index.php/blog/?article_type=xyz

***Problem here.***
http://example.com/index.php/blog/category1/?article_type=xyz

If i again select `xyz`, from 2nd drop down (ie type dropdown), it should give me Blog5 only -

How to achieve conditional filters in drop down in Javascript

Both filters works separately ie)

If i select value from 1st dd, it gives correct filters and same in 2nd dd

Problem is when i try do a child or 2nd level filter

Below is the code

> 1st dropdown

```
jQuery('#blogcat').on('change', function() {
    var baseurl ='<?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('wordpress/homepage')->getBlogHomepageUrl(); ?>'   
    var baseurl_events ='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>events'   
    var category_slug = jQuery(this).val();
    if(category_slug == 'events'){
        var categories_redirect = baseurl_events;
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", baseurl_events);
    }else{
        var categories_redirect = baseurl + category_slug;  
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", categories_redirect);
    }
});
```

> 2nd drop down

```
jQuery('#blogarticletype').on('change', function() {
    var baseurl ='<?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('wordpress/homepage')->getBlogHomepageUrl(); ?>'
    var baseurl_events ='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>events'
    var baseurl_glossary ='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>glossary'
    var baseurl_catalogs ='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>catalogs'

    var category_slug = jQuery('#blogcat').val();
    var article_slug = jQuery(this).val();
    if(article_slug == 'events'){
        var categories_redirect = baseurl_events;
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", baseurl_events);
    }
    else if(article_slug == 'glossary'){
        var categories_redirect = baseurl_glossary;
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", baseurl_glossary);
    }
    else if(article_slug == 'catalogs'){
        var categories_redirect = baseurl_catalogs;
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", baseurl_catalogs);
    }
    else if(article_slug == null || article_slug == ''){
        var categories_redirect = baseurl;
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", baseurl);
    }   
    else{           
        var redirect_url = baseurl+category_slug+'?article_type='+article_slug;
        alert(redirect_url);
        jQuery( location ).attr("href", redirect_url);
    }

});
```

Code on how my custom drop down filter works - **magento code UPDATED below**.

**Fishpig\Wordpress\Block\Post\List.php**

```
protected function _getPostCollection()
{
    //RAMD-641: Custom query to get the Article Filter types
    $artical_type = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('article_type');
    if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
        $this->_postCollection = $this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection();

        if ($this->_postCollection) {
            if ($this->getPostType()) {
                $this->_postCollection->addPostTypeFilter($this->getPostType());
                if(!empty($artical_type)) {
                    $posttypevalue = Mage::helper('wordpress')->getPostMetaData();
                    if(!empty($posttypevalue)) {
                        $this->_postCollection = $this->_postCollection->addFieldToFilter('ID',array('in' => $posttypevalue));
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($this->getPagerBlock()) {
                $this->getPagerBlock()->setCollection($this->_postCollection);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_postCollection;
}
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
public function getPostMetaData()
{
    $artical_type = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('article_type');
    try{
        if(!empty($artical_type)) {
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('new_db');
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
            $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
            $query = 'SELECT b.post_id FROM wp_posts AS a, wp_postmeta AS b WHERE a.ID=b.post_id AND b.meta_key="type" AND a.post_status="publish"';
            $query .= " AND b.meta_value LIKE '%".$artical_type."%' ORDER BY a.post_date DESC";
            //var_dump($query);
            $post_ids = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
            if(!empty($post_ids)) {
                $_post_id_array = array();
                foreach($post_ids as $post) {
                    $_post_id_array[] = $post['post_id'];
                }
                $_post_id_array = array_unique($_post_id_array);
                return $_post_id_array;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: so if you choose on the second dropdown, you get this address http://example.com/index.php/blog/category1/xyz ?

Comment: Yes i get that from 'redirect_url' of #blogarticletype in the address, but the filter is applied only from the 1st drop down ie only till https://example.com/index.php/blog/category1 even though the url is https://example.com/index.php/blog/category1/xyz

Comment: Can you please be precise when specifying the urls this code generates.  I see no way that the second function can generate a url which doesn’t end in `?article_type=something`

Comment: I think issue is not due to the js but the file that handle the request. Make sure if your file can handle this permalink type

Comment: I updated the URL in question @James, my 2nd drop down filter url would be https://example.com/index.php/blog/category1/?article_type=xyz

Comment: Can you please explain @RantoRasolomahefa, what you  meant by if the file cant handle the request

Comment: @Sushivam can you give us an url that works with both filters enabled ?

Comment: Not sure @RantoRasolomahefa, my local URL needs to be exposed globally in order for me to share or if there is anyway if you can come for a screenshare

Comment: @Sushivam an url written like example.com/... but works in your local server with both filters enabled

Comment: No I have mentioned as example.com here , my actual local URL is something like rauqaqa.com/index.php/blog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174500/discussion-between-ranto-rasolomahefa-and-sushivam).

Comment: I have updated the JS code in question and it related php code, im stuck as to where the root cause of the problem may be @RantoRasolomahefa